# Error de indentación Python

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en Python y estoy tratando de hacer una función que determine si un valor introducido por teclado es de tipo entero o no. La consola me marca "IndentationError: expected an indented block" en la línea 3.

```
    def validar_entero(num):
    if type(num) == True:
    else:
        print("No valido")
    return "Valido"


numero = int(input("Introduce un numero entero: "))

print(validar_entero(numero))
```

Comment: `def` debe estar en el mismo nivel que `numero`, te recomiendo usar alguna IDE para que no tengas estos problemas

Comment: Si, tenes un problema de indentación. La función esta al mismo nivel de indentación que `if type(num)`.

Comment: @AleBuo Ah, gracias por recordarme que esta pregunta aún estaba abierta. La formulé hace muchísimo. Ahora mismo marco la respuesta para el que tenga el mismo problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tienes varios errores en tu código
 Primero te recomiendo leer un tutorial, cada bloque de codigo en python se gestiona indentando voy a poner '|' para que lo veas visualmente

```
|def validar_entero(num):
|    |if type(num) == True:
|    |else:
|    |    |print("No valido")
|    |return "Valido"
|numero = int(input("Introduce un numero entero: "))
|print(validar_entero(numero))
```

como puedes ver, def inicia un bloque de código, tanto if como else inician unos subbloques donde debe ir algo

```
|def validar_entero(num):
|    |if type(num) == True:
|    |    |pass
|    |else:
|    |    |print("No valido")
|    |return "Valido"
|numero = int(input("Introduce un numero entero: "))
|print(validar_entero(numero))
```

de lo contrario te dara indentation error, pues el interprete espera encontrar un subbloque de código y no existe.