# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python

Necesito ayuda con este codigo , me aparece: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
... y no se como solucionarlo.

```
def abrir ():
    with open('BaseDeDatos.csv' , encoding='utf-8') as a:
              texto = a.read()


    lines = texto.split("\n")
    lines.pop()

    matriz = []

    for linea in lines:
        matriz.append(linea.split(','))
        return matriz

        a.close()



def crear():

     with open('BaseDeDatos.csv' , encoding='utf-8') as i:
              texto = i.read()


        lines = texto.split("\n")
        lines.pop()

        matriz = []

        for linea in lines:
            matriz.append(linea.split(","))
            return matriz

        i.close()

        print crear
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. `IndentationError` es porque escribe las indentaciones de manera incorrecta. Puede leer [esta pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/300572/error-de-indentaci%c3%b3n-python).

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios fallos de indentación

```
def abrir ():
    with open('BaseDeDatos.csv' , encoding='utf-8') as a:
```

texto lo tenias sobreindentado

```
        texto = a.read()
```

Estas lineas estaban al mismo nivel de indentación que with, lo suyo es que estubieran un nivel inferior quedando a la misma altura que la anterior

```
        lines = texto.split("\n")
        lines.pop()

        matriz = []

        for linea in lines:
            matriz.append(linea.split(','))
```

return estaba a a misma altura que matriz por lo que se ejecutaría justo después de esta finalizando el bucle for y la función

return finaliza la función por eso close se llama antes

```
        a.close() 
        return matriz
```

crear tiene exactamente los mismos fallos

```
def crear():

    with open('BaseDeDatos.csv' , encoding='utf-8') as i:
        texto = i.read()

        lines = texto.split("\n")
        lines.pop()

        matriz = []

        for linea in lines:
            matriz.append(linea.split(","))
        i.close()
        return matriz
```

si no llamas a la función esta no se ejecuta, le faltan los ()

```
print crear()
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la tabulación de `texto = a.read()`, debajo del `with`, que lo has puesto doble.