# Vdensidad=txtDen.get() IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Tags: python, tkinter

he estado desarrollando un programa en Python 3 acerca de densidad, masa y volumen, soy nuevo en el lenguaje, y me ha salido el error:

```
"File "ventana python tkinter.py", line 65
    Vdensidad=txtDen.get() IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"
```

Programe un botón para que calculara y sacara la densidad, volumen y masa dependiendo que se necesitara, esto ultimo es decir la necesidad de obtener un valor en especifico lo indico con un 0, es así como aplico las formulas necesarias para calcular.

Después fuera de las condiciones meto a los espacios de `label` las respuestas.

¿Podrían ayudarme?

Este es el código:

```
def calc():


    if Vdensidad==0:
        Vmasa=txtMas.get()
        Vvolumen=txtVol.get()
        Vdensidad=(float(Vmasa)/float(Vvolumen))


    if Vvolumen==0:
        Vmasa=txtMas.get()
        Vdensidad=txtDen.get()
        Vvolumen=(float(Vmasa)/float(Vdensidad))
    if Vmasa==0:
        Vdensidad=txtDen.get()
        Vvolumen=txtVol.get()
        Vmasa=(float(Vvolumen)*float(Vdensidad))


    lblres1.configure(text=Vdensidad)
    lblres2.configure(text=Vmasa)
    lblres3.configure(text=Vvolumen)


btnCALC= Button(ventana, text="Calcular", bg="red",fg="white",command=calc)
btnCALC.grid(column=0,row=4)
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/304082/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error es del tipo identación osea no estas dando el espacio de sangría en esa linea debes de dejar 4 espacios.

Ahora pregunto? los get() los capturas de widget Entry?

porque no veo declarado el tipo de dato de la variables? me refiero si el Entry recibe textvariable y si lo habias declarado porque le pones que sea float? cuando lo podrías haber hecho antes acuérdate que puedes declarar el tipo de variable como StringVar(), IntVar(),DobleVar() y creo que también BoleanVar().

Ahora me parece que puedes hacerlo mas simple si primero poner las variables 
y luego las calculas de acuerdo lo necesites ej: del primer calculo

```
def calc:

    if Vdensidad==0:
        Vmasa=txtMas.get()
        Vvolumen=txtVol.get()
        Vdensidad=(float(Vmasa)/float(Vvolumen))

def calc:


    Vmasa = txtMas.get()
    Vvolumen = txtVol.get()
    Vdensidad = Vmasa / Vvolumen   # Antes declara el tipo de variable para los entry

lblres1.config(text=Vdensidad)
```