# Ayuda para crear clase de la capa de la red neuronal

Tags: python, self

Hola estoy tratando de hacer mi primera red neuronal y estoy siguiendo los pasos de un ejercicio que vi y están resolviendo en Jupyter. Pero llega a un punto cuando tengo que crear la clase de la capa de la red neuronal y poner el siguiente código en el que no me funciona ya como lo hacen ahí. El código es este:

```
"class neural_layer():
def _init_(self ,n_conn , n_neur , atc_f):
self.act_f= act_f
self.b= np.random.rand(1, n_neur)* 2-1
self.W= np.random.rand(n_conn, n_neur)* 2-1"
```

Después que le doy correr para verificar si está bien, me sale el siguiente error

```
"File "<ipython-input-49-c3c4e724f00e>", line 2
    def _init_(self ,n_conn , n_neur , atc_f):
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block"
```

Lo intenté correr también en vs code y me aparece lo mismo. Creo que va relacionado con el self pero no sé por qué exactamente. Agradecería que alguien me ayudara para poder continuar . Gracias!! :)

Comment: Antes de hacer tu primer proyecto en Python, deberías conocer Python. Este lenguaje tiene la particularidad que los bucles se hacen con indentación, no con llaves o etiquetas como otros lenguajes. Mira esta referencia: [Error de Indentación en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/300572/error-de-indentaci%C3%B3n-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En python la identación es obligatoria. `class` va en el primer nivel, los métodos y atributos de clase en el siguiente y, después, va el contenido de los métodos:

```py
class neural_layer():
    def _init_(self ,n_conn , n_neur , atc_f):
        self.act_f= act_f
        self.b= np.random.rand(1, n_neur)* 2-1
        self.W= np.random.rand(n_conn, n_neur)* 2-1
```

La identación recomendada en python es con 4 espacios en blancos. Nunca uses tabuladores.

Comment: Oye muchas gracias, no me había fijado en ello.